# Runtime polymorphism by using Provider Package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection

How to apply run-time polymorphism by using **Provider** Package in **Flutter**?
I have an advanced use case. My app has a 'View Demo' button that brings the user into the app and he can view all the screens with some dummy data. This helps the user to view the whole app even before creating an account.

I'm using the repository pattern and have a Repo abstract class and implemented by *FirebaseRepo* with actual data and *MockRepo* with dummy data. I need to provide the Repository instance throughout the app.

When the user clicks the login button, the Repository should be swapped with *FirebaseRepo* and when the user clicks the 'View Demo' button, the Repository instance should swap with the *MockRepo*. Thus need to provide and swap dependencies at runtime by using the **Provider** package. How to accomplish this?

Though out the app, I should be able to access the repository by simply using `Provider.of<Repository>(context)` rather than, `Provider.of<RepositoryModel>(context).getRepository()` so that I can simply do, `Provider.of<Repository>(context).getUser()`

Answer (score 0):

Please try simple solution below.

```dart
abstract class Repository {}

class FirebaseRepo extends Repository {}

class MockRepo extends Repository {}
```

```dart
// on login
Provider<FirebaseRepo>(
  create: (_) => FirebaseRepo(),
  dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
  child: MainPage<FirebaseRepo>(),
)

// on mock
Provider<MockRepo>(
  create: (_) => MockRepo(),
  dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
  child: MainPage<MockRepo>(),
)
```

```dart
class MainPage<T extends Repository> extends StatefullWidget {
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState<T extends Repository>();
}
class _MainPageState<T extends Repository> extends State<MainPage> {
  /// BLoC of type T.
  T bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bloc = Provider.of<T>(context, listen: false);
  }

  ...
}
```